# Regular expression | Extract words with uppercase within 3 words from a preposition

Tags: regex, python-3.5

I am trying to extract cities and countries from several articles. The regular expression that I am using:

```
(at [A-Z](?:\w+)?|in [A-Z](?:\w+)?|of [A-Z](?:\w+)?)
```

It allows me to extract this kind of location:

```
of Mogadishu
in Istanbul
of Beletwein
```

However, it doesn't allow me to extract the location when is formulated as follows:

```
in downtown Tunis
in central Mogadishu
in a town near Mogadishu
```

What I would like to extract is  any word starting with an uppercase after prepositions like (in,of,through, at) within a range of 3 words.

[In the link there is a sample of the text corpus] (https://regex101.com/r/0DRayP/6) and the regular expression

Comment: A regular expression is probably not the way to do this - look into NLTK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
\b(?:at|in|of)\b[^A-Z]+([A-Z]\w*)
```

Answer (score 2):

`\b(at|in|of) (?:\w+\s){0,3}([A-Z]\w+)`

I believe that hits everything in your example text.

- `\b` makes sure the preposition is by itself and not part of another word.
- The first group hits a preposition, which is easily modifiable to add more.
- The second group isn't capturing and you can modify the number of additional words between the prep and location in the `{0,3}` bracket.
- The third group gets your location.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this (you can change number of words):

`(at|in|of)( \w+){0,2} [A-Z](?:\w+)?`